# Change *default* refresh rate for monitors on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv, refresh-rate

I have multi-monitor setup and i'm trying to connect my TV as another monitor. TV doesn't support 60 Hz refresh rate: when i'm enabling it in resolution&presentation screen it turns on, but there will be no picture on TV until i manually go into "additional settings" and lower refresh rate to 30 Hz for it.

Problem is - this setting resets whenever i change monitor configuration. Disable one of 2 monitors - refresh rate for TV resets to 60, no image. Add third monitor - 60 again. But worst part is - it also happens if i disable all other monitors - TV will reset to 60 and there will be no image.

I need to either:

- force windows to set 30 Hz refresh rate as a default when new monitor is connected.
- force windows to remember refresh rate for specific monitor.

Currently i'm fiddling with macro recorder to try to change refresh rate blindly, but that's not exactly a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, universe decided to show me off as a fool yet again. Found a solution
The answer is simple: NVIDIA control panel. Unlike windows settings window, values that you set in NVIDIA control panel WILL remain after monitor disconnection and will be applied next time you enable it.
Hope it'll help somebody someday.